# Testing that a constant matches an interval

Tags: z3, smt

Given the following simple example:

```py
s = Solver()

Z = IntSort()
a = Const('a', Z)

s.add(a >= 0)
s.add(a < 10)

print(s.check(a > 5)) # sat
```

Up until the last line, `a` has an implied range of `0 <= a < 10` - for which `a > 5` does *not* satisfy. However, `.check()` tells z3 that "this is true" - which is not what I'm after.

Is there a way to ask z3 to test if `a > 5` given the existing set of constraints, and have z3 interpret this as "make sure this is true given everything else we know about `a`"?

---

EDIT: Okay I think I figured it out. Since z3 tries to find a model that satisfies all constraints, I should instead check for the *inverse* to see if it finds a solution - in which case, my check would not hold.

In this case, my "test" function would become:

```py
def test(s, expr):
    return s.check(Not(expr)) == unsat
```

thus...

```py
s = Solver()

Z = IntSort()
a = Const('a', Z)

s.add(a >= 0)
s.add(a < 10)

print(s.check(a > 5)) # sat

print(s.check(Not(a > 5)) == unsat) # false, test failed
s.add(a > 8)

print(s.check(Not(a > 5)) == unsat) # true, test passed
```

Is that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you are doing is essentially correct, though not idiomatic. When you issue `s.check(formula)`, you're telling z3 to show the satisfiability of all the other constraints you `add`'ed, along with `formula`; i.e., their conjunction. So, the way you set it up, it gives you the correct result.

Here's some more detail. Since what you want to prove looks like:

```py
Implies(And(lower, upper), required)
```

the typical way of doing this would be to assert its negation, and then check if it is satisfiable. That is, you'd check if:

```py
Not(Implies(And(lower, upper), required))
```

is satisfiable. Recall that `Implies(a, b)` is equivalent to `Or(Not(a), b)`, so a little bit of Boolean logic transforms the above to:

```py
And(And(lower, upper), Not(required))
```

What you are doing is to `add` the first conjunct above (i.e., `And(lower, upper)`) to the solver itself, and then use the second conjunct `Not(required)` as an argument to check to see if you get `unsat`. If you do, then you get a "proof" that `required` always holds. Otherwise you get a counterexample.

I should add, however, that this is not idiomatic usage of z3py and calls to `check` with a formula. The latter is usually used with a list of assumptions, and figuring out which subset of them was unsatisfiable with a call to `get-unsat-assumptions`. These applications typically come from model-checking problems. For details, see Section 4.2.5 of https://smtlib.cs.uiowa.edu/papers/smt-lib-reference-v2.6-r2021-05-12.pdf which discusses the semantics of `check-sat-assuming`, which is the SMTLib equivalent of calling `check` with extra assumptions.

To solve your problem in more idiomatic z3, one would instead write something like:

```py
from z3 import *

s = Solver()
a = Int('a')

lower    = a >= 0
upper    = a < 10
required = a > 5

formula = Implies(And(lower, upper), required)

# assert the negation
s.add(Not(formula))
r = s.check()
if r == sat:
    print("Not valid, counterexample:")
    print(s.model())
elif r == unsat:
    print("Valid!")
else:
    print("Solver said:", r)
```

This prints:

```
Not valid, counterexample:
[a = 0]
```

And if you change to `lower = a >= 8`, it'll print:

```
Valid!
```

Bottom line, what you're doing is correct but not very idiomatic usage for `check-sat-assuming`. A simpler way is to simply assert the negation of the implication that your lower/upper bounds imply the required inequality and check if the result is `unsat` instead.

Comment: Great answer, thank you. In my case, there wouldn't be a clear lower/upper bound at every call site, but instead the exact set of constraints would be built up over a longer period. Further, the assertion isn't necessarily always a bounds check - it was just an example I used to illustrate my point. But your answer more than sufficiently covers what it is I needed to know :) Thank you very much!